# Virtualbox: USB devices captured but not attached

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I'm using an Ubuntu 16.04 guest on Windows 10. 
I have this strange problem: all USB devices are not attached even the ones that were working fine with a filter. 
The devices are captured but not attached. If I try to click on a device under "Devices->USB->" I receive a message saying that the device is busy.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at UpperFilters key at this path **Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}** in the Windows registry.

Remove the UpperFilters.

For example Wireshark setup the UpperFilters and stopped all devices from being attached to VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the extension pack from here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Be sure that you are not already using that pendrive in your host or guest.

And check in "Devices->USB" if your are choosing right type (usb 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0)